# How to populate Jvector Map with countries from database?

Tags: php, ajax, database, jvectormap

(I am new to Javascript and jQuery..) I have a dashboard and I want to display a map that shows the countries where participants of a particular event are coming from. With this, I opted with [Jvector Map](http://jvectormap.com/). I am having a hard time displaying the countries in the map, coming from my database.

dashboard.js

```
var mapData = {};
$('#world-map').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    regionStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: '#e4e4e4',
            "fill-opacity": 0.9,
            stroke: 'none',
            "stroke-width": 0,
            "stroke-opacity": 0
        }
    },

    series: {
        regions: [{
            values: function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"includes/sql/fetchcountries.php",
                    method:"GET",
                    data:mapData,
                    dataType:"json",
                    success: function(data){
                        mapData = data;          
                        console.log(mapData);
                    }
                })
            },
            scale: ["#1ab394", "#22d6b1"],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
        }]
    },
});
```

fetch.php

```
<?php 
   require '../auth/dbh.inc.auth.php';
   $id = $_SESSION['ntc_id'];

   $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(participants.p_country) FROM ntc_participants
                       INNER JOIN participants ON participants.p_id=ntc_participants.p_id_fk
                       WHERE ntc_participants.ntc_id_fk=?");

  $data = array();
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
  if($result->num_rows === 0);
  if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $data[] = [
      $row['p_country'] => 0 ]; //the value 0 is just a placeholder.. The jvector map feeds on this format: "US":298, "SA": 200
 }
  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Could anyone be gracious enough to walk me through all the wrong things I'm doing in my code? Appreciate all the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is asynchronous, so You are creating the map before the data has been downloaded.

Initialize the map with empty values for Your region:

```
$('#world-map').vectorMap({
  ...
     values: {}
  ...
});
```

Then, whenever You need to show the data, set it dynamically:

```
$.get("includes/sql/fetchcountries.php", function(data) {
  var mapObj = $("#world-map").vectorMap("get", "mapObject");
  mapObj.series.regions[0].setValues(data);
});
```

During the ajax invocation and data download maybe You can show a spinner (please look at `beforeSend` inside the jQuery full ajax documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Here is the reference for `setValues`:

http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/jvm-dataseries/

Answer (score 0):

http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/all/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.CD?format=json&date=2018

This link will give you up-to-date stats for most common indicators via json - and then you can pluck whatever data that you like. I don't have all the code yet, as I am working on this today too.

This answers the question above whenever your database can also present JSON

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    console.log("loaded")
    fetchCountryData()
})

function fetchCountryData () {
    fetch('http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/all/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.CD?format=json&date=2018')
    // 
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
        let country.id = data[1]
    let indicator.id = data[1]
    create-GDP-Data(country.id,indicator.id)
})  
}

function create-GDP-Data(country.id,indicator.id){
    let gdpData = ?
}

$('#world-map-gdp').vectorMap({
  map: 'world_mill',
  series: {
    regions: [{
      values: gdpData,
      scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
      normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
    }]
  },
  onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code){
    el.html(el.html()+' (GDP - '+gdpData[code]+')');
  }
});
```